# C# char/byte encoding equality

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have some code to dump strings to stdout to check their encoding, it looks like this:

```
    private void DumpString(string s)
    {   
        System.Console.Write("{0}: ", s);
        foreach (byte b in s)
        {   
            System.Console.Write("{0}({1}) ", (char)b, b.ToString("x2"));
        }       
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Consider two strings, each of which appear as "ë", but with different encodings. DumpString will produce the following output:

> ë: e(65)(08)
>   ë: ë(eb)

The code looks like this:

```
DumpString(string1);
DumpString(string2);
```

How can I convert string2, using the System.Text.Encoding, to be byte equivalent to string1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don't have different encodings.  Strings in C# are always UTF-16 (thus, you shouldn't use `byte` to iterate over strings because you'll lose the top 8 bits).  What they have is different [**normalization forms**](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Your first string is "\u0065\u0308": LATIN SMALL LETTER E + COMBINING DIAERESIS.  This is the **decomposed** form (NFD).

The second is "\u00EB": LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS.  This is the **precomposed** form (NFC).

You can convert between them with [`string.Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`String.Normalize` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx).